# Oracle recursive hierarchical query with condition on the leaf level

Tags: oracle, recursion, conditional-statements, hierarchical

I want to do a hierarchical query with a condition on the leaf level.

I would like the query to filter all the father - child relationships where the leaf level statisfies the condition : id LIKE '3%'

The table t is :

```
ParentId,Id
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTE', 'VTP');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTP', '202');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SER', '606');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SER', '609');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('GIF', '301');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ECH', '302');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'MER');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '312');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '313');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '314');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MES', '318');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'PRE');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'PAP');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('STA', '317');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('NIV', 'ANS');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNM', '497');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNU', '496');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNC');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNC', '491');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('NUL', 'NIV');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('NIV', 'VTE');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTE', 'VTC');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTC', '100');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTP', '204');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTP', '205');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTA', '500');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SER', '600');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('NIV', 'PUB');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ECH', '303');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '305');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '306');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '309');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PAP', '605');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SEP', 'PBC');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PBC', '601');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SEP', 'STA');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('NIV', 'TRA');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNP', '498');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNM');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNE');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNR');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNR', '493');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNF', '492');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTC', '101');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTC', '102');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTE', 'VTA');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTE', 'SER');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('AUT', '900');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'CPR');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '310');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '311');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '604');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'MES');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MES', '316');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SEP', 'RSF');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('RSF', '608');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('TRA', 'TRP');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('TRP', '603');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNP');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNU');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNG');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNF');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTC', '104');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTC', '105');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTP', '200');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTP', '201');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTP', '203');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTA', '400');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('VTE', 'AUT');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('CPR', '602');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'GIF');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PUB', 'ECH');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '307');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('MER', '308');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PRE', '304');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('PRE', '315');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('NIV', 'SEP');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('TRP', '607');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ANS', 'ZNA');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNA', '499');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNG', '495');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ZNE', '494');
COMMIT;
```

I initialy thought that I could use something like :

```
SELECT ParentId, Id
FROM t
WHERE  id LIKE '3%' 
start with ParentId ='NIV'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Id = ParentId
```

For example, 
302's father is ECH
ECH's father is PUB
PUB's father is NIV

But the query displays only the level 0 relationships :
302's father is ECH

It discards all the higher levels to the root :
ECH's father is PUB
PUB's father is NIV

I came up with the solution below.

But, the child-parents loop is hard coded, which defeats the purpose of the hierarchical query where the number of child - parent Relationships is automatically identified.

```
SELECT parentid, id
FROM t
WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT parentid
   FROM t
   WHERE 
   id IN 
     (SELECT parentid
      FROM t
      WHERE id LIKE '3%'
      start with parentid='NIV' 
      CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parentid)
      start with parentid ='NIV' 
      CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parentid)
OR 
ccomuse IN 
  (SELECT parentid 
   FROM t
   WHERE id LIKE '3%'
   start with parentid ='NIV' 
   CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parentid )
OR 
id LIKE '3%' 
start with parentid ='NIV' 
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parentid
```

Is there a way to extract all the child-parent relationships without hard coding the 2 Inside loops, ie with a recursive method that automatically reach the root ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the sys_connect_by_path() function to itemise the elemnts in the hierarchy, and filter on the right-most?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions171.htm#i1038266

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might have overlook something, but I don't really understand how I could use sys_connect_by_path() function to return a 2 columns table with the Child-Father relationships based on a leaf level filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build tree from wrong end :-)

```
SELECT distinct ParentId, Id
FROM t
start with Id LIKE '3%' 
CONNECT BY Id = prior ParentId and Id <> 'NIV'
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a910/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter all the father - child relationships where the leaf level satisfies the condition then you need to specify the condition in the connect by clause. It will eliminate the unnecessary node and it's child nodes from the output.If you specify the condition in the where clause then child nodes will display without the parent node, so, output will not be meaningful.